# MG8Q6ES42 - N CHANNEL IGBT

Tags: motor, power-electronics, switching, igbt

I found this "MG8Q6ES42 - N CHANNEL IGBT" power switching control motor hybrid integrated circuit between some old motor application circuit boards. Although I found datasheet for it, I didn't found any test circuits or something alike (usually datasheets contain something like that).

Anyone knows how could I test it just to check if it is still operational for motor application circuits or other?

I haven't had any experience with motor control ICs until now, and I think it is wasteful to throw it away, especially since it price isn't so low either.

Here is the equivalent circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a three output motor driver.  You could either configure this into high-low-high or low-high-low to drive two different motors in opposite direction.  EU-EV-EW-EX-EY-EZ seems to be test point or emitter connections for all 6 IGBTs.

Comment: @12Lapointep : What can I do with it? What "kind" of circuit?

Comment: Possibly a triple half-bridge controller to drive motors.  You would possibly need a pre-driver IC to make sure you are not switching GU-GX at the same time, which would create shoot-through current and damage the chip.  The only thing I am confused about this is the "E" connections... What are those?

Comment: @12Lapointep The E connections are probably low-current connections to measure voltage at those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module is for driving a 3-phase motor coils from a single DC bus. You would need gate drivers and a bunch of other stuff to make it operational for the original purpose. The high side IGBTs need a gate drive above the positive rail so those need a supply on top of that rail or a bootstrapped drive and continuous switching.

IGBTs are driven similarly to n-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs- about 10-15V on the gate to turn them on, and 0 or perhaps a bit negative voltage to turn them off, but 0V will do for testing. You can test each IGBT individually (just leave other connections open) with a 12V supply and a small test load (such as an automotive tail lamp bulb).

Comment: I'd just add that while testing one IGBT is better to short GE each of the others.  Gates may remaing charged and thru the diodes  mess-up test results

Comment: As @carloc says, short the gate to emitter on unused transistors or connect ~100K resistors on each and apply voltage across that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : You wrote "short the gate", what do you mean by that (by "short")?

Comment: Connect the gate pin (eg. GU) to the emitter (eg. EU) of all the transistors you are *not* testing directly or through a 100K resistor (that's 6 resistors total). For the bottom transistor it would be GX to EX etc. Otherwise the gate can hold a charge from your previous test and confuse the results because the transistor can remain on.